# How to make SendGrid run without blocking?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sendgrid

Here is my code

```
public static void sendEmail(string sendto, string subject, string template, Object model)
{
    SendGridAPIClient sg = new SendGridAPIClient(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SendGridAPIKey"]);
    Email from = new Email(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EmailSender"]);
    Email to = new Email(sendto);
    var templateFolder = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "EmailTemplates");
    var tpl = File.OpenText(templateFolder + "\\" + template).ReadToEnd();
    string textbody = Engine.Razor.RunCompile(tpl, template, null, model);
    Content content = new Content("text/plain", textbody);
    Mail mail = new Mail(from, subject, to, content);
    dynamic response = sg.client.mail.send.post(requestBody: mail.Get());
}
```

This functions is called in many places. How can I make this function run without blocking the multiple places this functions is called?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn636893(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
using System.Web.Hosting;

HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem((ct) => sendEmail(sendto, subject, template, model));
```

Comment: Thanks, but don't seem to get emails now for some reason though API return looks good